# Can't find a directory vie unlink

Tags: php, sql

The file I'm working on is 1 directory above.

The image is in this path

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnKjZ.png]

But I got this error

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsrxO.png]

This is the code I have:

```
$ver=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from slides where id = '".$_POST['id']."'");
$mostra=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ver);

unlink("../img/slide/'".$mos['img']."'");
```

If I use the normal name instead of the one I go get in the database, It deletes it.

***SOLVED***

```
unlink("../img/slide/".$mos['img']);
```

Just needed to remove the '' in the unlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a rogue `'` in your `unlink()`. You can see it's trying to remove `'1.jpg'` which doesn't exist (I'm assuming the file name is `1.jpg` - without the `'`.)

Change your `unlink()` to remove the `'` around the variable.

```
unlink("../img/slide/".$mos['img']);
```

Comment: No worries :) Please consider [accepting the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) to close your question and let others know what worked for you should they have the same issue. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/246338